# Manipulate Var Char column in Mysql DB if inserted by VB.Net Now()

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

Stupidly, the only way i could get a VB.Net program to insert a timestamp into a mysql db was using Now() in the VB and putting the column as Var Char in the Mysql DB. Have i royally screwed myself or can i still pull this back in PHP and manipulate the data, ie select * from test where date between...etc.

How does mysql interpret a var char column in terms of dates/times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't fix the table properly (e.g. change the datatype), you can always use CAST() or CONVERT() in your SQL.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Comment: so i could convert "Var Char" column into "Timestamp" type?

Comment: Actually if you're using mySQL 5 or higher, it looks like an easier way would be the built-in str_to_date function.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date